# Use openssl s_client with 3des keying option 2 (112 bit key)

Tags: openssl

(How) Is it possible to tell openssl's `s_client` tool to use keying option 2 for 3DES (meaning use two different keys only, resulting in a key size of 112 bits; [see Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES))?

Currently the closest I got is

```
openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -tls1 -cipher DES-CBC3-SHA \
    -debug -msg -state -status -CApath /.../cacerts/ </dev/null
```

But with that command keying option 1 (tree different keys, 168 bit key length) is used.

Tools like http://ssllabs.com seem to be able to "simulate" for example IE8 on Win XP which seems to use 3DES with keying option 2...

Answer (score 1):

**You can't.** The standard SSL/TLS protocols that use "3DES" use 24 bytes of key for keying option 1 (actually 168 bits key and 24 bits obsolete parity which is ignored). See `3DES_EDE_CBC` in the table and subsequent legend in [appendix C of the standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#appendix-C) and entry for `Data Encryption Standard` in [the glossary](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#appendix-B). **OpenSSL implements the standard** as it must to interoperate with other implementations.

What SSLLabs is saying is that 3DES with 168 bits key only provides **112 bits of strength** due to a meet-in-the-middle attack (generic to any iterated cipher, not just 3DES). See

https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6345/why-is-triple-des-using-three-different-keys-vulnerable-to-a-meet-in-the-middle(attack)

https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/14659/find-out-which-keying-option-is-being-used-in-triple-des

https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/16073/why-is-triple-des-not-vulnerable-to-meet-in-the-middle-attacks

and especially https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/22279/discrepancy-with-reported-key-size-for-ede-ciphers-in-qualys-ssl-labs which is the same question from the correct end.